# "image not found" with scipy.stats

Tags: statistics, scipy

Does anybody know what could cause this error with python?

I have scipy installed but when I try to use scipy.stats it complains that "image not found"

Comment: Please give the complete error message, along with the code that triggered the error.  Also explain how you installed scipy, and what version it is.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the DMG file I used for my python (form NASA's stsci) is missing gfortran